# How do I add two large non-negative integers using char array in C?

Tags: c, string, addition

I am making a program to add two large non-negative integers (each large integer contains at most 100 digits). In my program, however, it is giving out wrong outputs for most cases.

I've completed the `main()` function, but I believe the problem with my code is within the `AddTwoBigNumbers()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_INT_LENGTH = 100;

void AddTwoBigNumbers(char bigN[], char bigM[], char sum[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    while (1) {
        int sum1 = count;
        if (bigM[index]) {
            sum1 += bigM[index] - '0';
            index++;
        }
        if (bigN[index2]) {
            sum1 += bigN[index2] - '0';
            index2++;
        }
        sum[i] = sum1 % 10 + '0';
        i++;
        count = sum1 / 10;
        if (bigM[index] == 0 && bigN[index2] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count) {
        sum[i] = count + '0';
        i++;
    }
    sum[i] = 0;

    int x, len = 0;
    for (x = 0; sum[x]; ++x) {
        ++len;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < len / 2; ++x) {
        sum[len] = sum[x];
        sum[x] = sum[len - x - 1];
        sum[len - x - 1] = sum[len];
    }
}

int main() {
    char bignum[2][MAX_INT_LENGTH]; // bignum[0] and bignum[1] are to store the digits of the two input number
    char sum[MAX_INT_LENGTH + 1];     // to store the sum of the two big numbers

    // read in two numbers
    scanf("%s", bignum[0]);
    scanf("%s", bignum[1]);

    // calculate sum of the two numbers
    AddTwoBigNumbers(bignum[0], bignum[1], sum);

    // display the sum on screen
    printf("%s\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample cases are as follows:

Input:

```
1
999999999999999999999999999
```

Output:

```
1000000000000000000000000000
```

My output:

```
1000000000000000000000000000
```

Input:

```
999999999999999999999999999
999999999999999999999999999
```

Output:

```
1999999999999999999999999998
```

My output:

```
1999999999999999999999999989
```

Comment: What hapens when you add: 9 + 9, 9 + 99, 99 + 9, 99 + 99

Comment: This seems to be the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I also recommend that in the future you don't write full programs before doing basic testing like this. Instead write a very small piece of code, build (with extra warnings enabled) and fix possible errors and warnings, then test the small piece of code. Then you write another small little piece of code, build (and fix problems) and test. And so on. That way, it will be much easier to solve problems, debug code, and limit your searching for bugs to the last little piece of code you've added.

Comment: And be wary of code that you copy-paste. If you need to do the same thing multiple times, instead of copy-paste the code and make small changes (that sometimes are forgotten or wrong), put common code into functions. Even if it's just a couple of lines. Functions are also much easier to test and debug in isolation.

Comment: @Kira: You are adding the digits from left to right, which cannot possibly work, i.e. if you enter `1000` and `34`, your function will first add `1` and `3`. I believe you also don't terminate the `sum` variable with `\0` after reversing it. So start by reversing your inputs, terminate the sum, and learn how to step through your code using a debugger using simpler inputs which are have obvious results.

Comment: so kira are any of these answers helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Your function add the two integers from left to right. Try this method, It's an algorithm that add from the back to the front (Array parameters are usually degraded to pointers, So `char *bigN` is equal to `char bigN[]` here):

```
void AddTwoBigNumbers(char *bigN, char *bigM, char* sum)
{
    int add = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int nbigN = strlen(bigN)-1;
    int nbigM = strlen(bigM)-1;
    while (nbigN >= 0 || nbigM >= 0)
    {
        int N = 0, M = 0;
        if (nbigN >= 0)
        {
            N = bigN[nbigN] - '0';
            nbigN--;
        }
        if (nbigM >= 0)
        {
            M = bigM[nbigM] - '0';
            nbigM--;
        }
        add = N + M + count;
        sum[index++] = add % 10 + '0';
        count = add / 10;
    }
    if (count)
        sum[index++] = count + '0';
    sum[index] = 0;
    int nsum = strlen(sum);
    for (int i = 0, j = nsum - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        char c = sum[i];
        sum[i] = sum[j];
        sum[j] = c;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
int strlen(char* buf)
{
    int len = 0;
    if (buf == NULL)
        return len;
    while (*buf++)
        len++;
    return len;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can only use the <stdio.h> header for this program.

Comment: Just need to re-write the `strlen()` function.

Answer (score 1):

In the program that you posted you are considering the most significant digits first.

Try considering the Least significant digits first and then work your way towards the more significant digits.

Take into account the carry values that may be generated and add them to the next set of values and reset the value of carry accordingly.

Bear in mind that the numbers are being treated as characters. Subtract `'0'` from the character when you need the integer value and convert them back to character form by adding `'0'`.

Adjust for cases where the lengths of `bigM` and `bigN` are not the same as well.

If all digits of `bigM` are over use the values of `bigN` and carry value, if any, to calculate all the remaining digits of `sum` and the other way around.

And finally, after all the digits of both the input numbers are exhausted, check if there is any carry remaining and add that to `sum` as well.

You may calculate and insert values to `sum` in the reverse fashion and reverse the string later if you like.

Don't forget to nul (`'\0'`) terminate `sum` at the end.

---

You could do something like

```
void AddTwoBigNumbers(char bigN[], char bigM[], char sum[])
{
    int i=strlen(bigM)-1, j=strlen(bigN)-1, k, carry=0;
    for(k=0; i>=0 && j>=0; --i, --j, ++k)
    {
        sum[k] = (bigM[i]-'0' + bigN[j]-'0' + carry)%10 + '0';
        carry = (bigM[i]-'0' + bigN[j]-'0' + carry)/10;
    }

    for(; i>=0; --i, ++k)
    {
        sum[k] = (bigM[i]-'0' + carry)%10 + '0'; 
        carry = (bigM[i]-'0' + carry)/10;
    }
    for(; j>=0; --j, ++k)
    {
        sum[k] = (bigN[j]-'0' + carry)%10 + '0'; 
        carry = (bigN[j]-'0' + carry)/10;
    }
    if(carry!=0)
    {
        sum[k++]=carry+'0';
    }
    sum[k]=0;

    //Reversing string
    for(int t=0; t<n/2; ++t)
    {
        char temp=sum[t];
        sum[t]=sum[n-1-t];
        sum[n-1-t]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can only use the <stdio.h> header for this program.